# Why is my API having a fetch error in my react

Tags: react-hooks

I am creating a react application which gets an input from a user and then uses that input to fetch information from an api when the button is clicked. I am new to React and I keep getting a failed to fetch error.

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react"

function App() {
   const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
   const inputRef = useRef();

 useEffect(() => {
 inputRef.current.focus();
  }, [])

 return (
   <div className="App">
   <input ref={inputRef} value={userName} onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)} />
  <button onClick={async function myAsyncFunc() {
    let response = await fetch(`https://api.nationalize.it?name=${userName}`);
    let result = await response.json();

    console.log(result)
  }}>Submit</button>
 </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `fetch` fails, your requesty is wrong, which has nothing to do with React. https://api.nationalize.it does not exist, so any request will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The correct API to use for nationality prediction based on a given name is https://api.nationalize.io?name=michael. The URL https://api.nationalize.it seems to be incorrect or outdated, and it should be avoided.

For more details about the API, you can check out https://nationalize.io/, where you can find additional information and documentation regarding the service.